# Can i perform cupping on my sister?

Tags: hadith, fiqh, sharia, awrah, mahram

I am a Muslim male. I wanted to know if I can perform cupping on my sister since there is no female hijama specialist available in our city (Im a hijama specialist myself). There is a hadith narrated by Jaabir ibn Abdullah (RA) where Umm Salama (RA) sought permission from the Messenger (PBUH) to undergo cupping. The Prophet (PBUH) then directed Abu Teeba (RA) to perform the cupping. Jaabir ibn Abdullah (RA) mentioned, "I think he (SAWS) said that Abu Teeba (may Allah be pleased with him) is her brother through breastfeeding or a young boy who didn't reach puberty" [Saheeh Muslim - Hadith No: 5708, Sunan Abu Dawud - Hadith No: 4102, Sunan-Ibn-Maajah Hadith No: 3480]. So, does this mean I am allowed to perform cupping on my sister?
(We both are adults)